# What is the c# equivalent of this weird VB syntax for property?

Tags: c#, vb.net, properties

I found the following syntax as a VB.NET property and I'm trying to convert it to c#, but I'm not sure how to accomplish that.

```
Public Property SomeText(ByVal someEnumThing as SomeEnum) As String
    Get
        Select Case someEnumThing
            //figure out what string to return
        End Select
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value as String)
        Select Case someEnumThing
            //figure out what string to set
        End Select
    End Set
End Property
```

I've never seen a property done like this before, any ideas?

Comment: C# does not support "indexed properties", that is, properties which take parameters. VB does. FYI, in C# 4 we will allow certain *uses* of indexed properties on COM objects; it is hard to call indexed properties on legacy COM objects that were designed to be called from VB. But we do not plan to support definition of new indexed properties in C# at this time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess you're referring to the arguments for the property. Well, as far as I know, C# only supports them for indexers, which cannot have a name (e.g. `this[SomeEnum someEnumThing] {}`).

If you want to get a similar behavior, you can create a helper class with an indexer property and use it to expose the "name" of the property:

```
public class YourClass {
    public struct SomeTextProperty {
        private readonly YourClass owner;

        internal SomeTextProperty(YourClass owner) {
            this.owner = owner;
        }

        public string this[SomeEnum someEnumThing] {
            get {
                return owner.GetSomeText(someEnumThing);
            }
            set {
                owner.SetSomeText(someEnumThing, value);
            }
        }
    }

    public SomeTextProperty SomeText {
        get {
            return new SomeTextProperty(this);
        }
    }

    private string GetSomeText(SomeEnum someEnumThing) {
        // implementation to get it
    }

    private void SetSomeText(SomeEnum someEnumThing, string value) {
        // implementation to set it
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, Ayende wrote a small trick to "get" named indexers in C# in his Rhino.Commons library.

Comment: @Lucero You nailed it, I was hoping there would be a c# equivalent, but I'm thinking I'm just screwed now. =(

Comment: @Joseph: well, not really. You *could* conceivably have another property to represent the SomeEnum parameter. Then inside the get/set as provided by @Andrew Hare you would reference the new property.

Comment: +1 - and updated my post with an example of what I mentioned above.

Comment: @Ahmad Yeah but that would break legacy code so that won't work.  I'm going to have to refactor the legacy code first and then migrate it.

Comment: Ah you beat me. It is possible to create the exact same functionality in C# by creating a specialized class that uses indexes and takes the parent class as a parameter. In this way it can notify the parent class of the index being used and would allow you to give it a name. Depending on how much time it would take to refactor the legacy code you may want to consider this option instead.

Answer (score 4):

Hmm... maybe the [`switch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28VS.71%29.aspx) statement?

Answer (score 4):

It is impossible to create a Property in C# which has arguments, unless it's the default property:

```
public double this[int index]
{
  get {...}
  set {...}
}
```

Just one of those areas where VB differs from C#.
It is not recommended to use syntax like this since you will not be able to use that property from a C# project that references this assembly.

Comment: Actually when VB.Net generates indexed properties it also generates "set_indexedPropertyName" and "get_indexedPropertyName" methods. It's not a property anymore from C# perspective but the code written as an indexed property in VB is still usable via these methods.

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about the fact that the property is parameterized...

There's no direct translation for this in c# that I know of. Basically this is carryover from VB6 where you could make this weird quasi-collection property for a class. The easiest way to get similar functionality is to create a dictionary object and either publicly expose it or create an accessor. Where the VB code accesses this property like `Class.SomeText("SomeKey")` your C# code will become `Class.SomeDictionaryProperty["SomeKey"]`

Unfortunately this still isn't quite the same since the collection accessor won't be able to "see" the index value. This has been a minor source of frustration for me as well in the past coming from a VB background.

Answer (score 2):

The Select Case will be a [switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28VS.71%29.aspx) statement. Is that what you are specifically referring to?

EDIT: here's what I was referring to in my comment to @Lucero's answer to get close to the VB.NET syntax.

```
private SomeEnum SomeEnumThing { get; set; }
public string SomeText {
    get {
        switch (SomeEnumThing) {
        //figure out what string to return
        }
    }
    set {
        switch (SomeEnumThing) {
        //figure out what string to set
        }
   }
```

}